# UWP Windows 10 и OAuth2

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, oauth2, windows-10-mobile

UWP Windows 10. C#

Необходимо авторизоваться на сервере с помощью логина и пароля по протоколу OAuth.

Что есть:

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Request token endpoint
- Access token endpoint
- Authorize URL
- Само собой Login и Password

Для WP8-8.1 есть библиотека AsyncOAuth но на Windows 10 она не работает. Подскажите самые просты варианты авторизации под UWP Win 10?

P.S. Смотрел пример, написал такой код:

```
        string SigBaseStringParams = "oauth_consumer_key=" + ConsumerKey;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + nonce;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + timeStamp;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_token=" + request_token;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";

        string SigBaseString = "POST&";
        SigBaseString = Uri.EscapeDataString(AccessTokenEndpoint) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(SigBaseStringParams);

        string Signature = GetSignature(SigBaseString, ConsumerSecret);

        HttpStringContent httpContent = new HttpStringContent("oauth_verifier=" + oauth_verifier, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        string authorizationHeaderParams = "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + ConsumerKey +
            "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce +
            "\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\"," +
            " oauth_signature=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Signature) +
            "\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp +
            "\", oauth_token=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(request_token) +
            "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("OAuth", authorizationHeaderParams);
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(AccessTokenEndpoint), httpContent);
        string response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

код получения signature:

```
string GetSignature(string sigBaseString, string consumerSecretKey)
    {
        IBuffer KeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(consumerSecretKey + "&", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        MacAlgorithmProvider HmacSha1Provider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
        CryptographicKey MacKey = HmacSha1Provider.CreateKey(KeyMaterial);
        IBuffer DataToBeSigned = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(sigBaseString, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        IBuffer SignatureBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(MacKey, DataToBeSigned);
        string Signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(SignatureBuffer);
        return Signature;
    }
```

requestToken и validationToken получаю нормально, но в последнем запросе получаю строку "oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=POST...". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAuthenticationBroker , http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/09/windows-10-app-with-integrated-keycloak.html

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо смотрел, дополнил вопрос...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему портированием AyncOauth на UWP Win 10
[NuGet оригинала](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncOAuth/)